# Can i put Many Pictures links in dialogflow and send only one Randomly

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am new to dialogflow. I learned some things the previous month, but I am still searching for how to put a lot of pictures in intent and sending only one to the user, not all of them, and randomly, such as text responses as a kind of entertainment inside the Agent ...
Note :
I linked the client to Facebook Messenger and I want to send the photo there
Can i do this?

Comment: Could you be more specific on your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using Dialogflow-fulfillment library to respond to webhook requests this should do the trick.

You can store whatever type of response that you want to send in an array...

For example, I'll choose an array of plain text responses

```
const responses = [
    "I didn't get that. Can you say it again?",
    'I missed what you said. What was that?',
    'Sorry, could you say that again?',
    'Sorry, can you say that again?',
    'Can you say that again?',
    "Sorry, I didn't get that. Can you rephrase?",
    'Sorry, what was that?',
    'One more time?',
    'What was that?',
    'Say that one more time?',
    "I didn't get that. Can you repeat?",
    'I missed that, say that again?'
  ]
```

Given the array you can generate a random number between 0 (most programming languages index from 0) and the length of the array.

```
const index = Math.floor((Math.random() * responses.length) + 1)
```

In the above case, index is assigned to any number between 0 and 11. You can then pass this index into the array to randomly choose 1 value.

```
agent.add(responses[index])
```

You can take this concept and apply it to any response type you want.

Hope this does the trick for you!

Comment: op is looking for console solution